# Scaling the mtpro2 fonts to work with Baskerville

Tags: math-mode, xetex, fontsize, mtpro

I'm using the MathTime Professional II (mtpro2) fonts with the Monotype Baskerville family. The font used for math letters in mtpro2 is Times New Roman Italic, and this can look quite good when combined with Baskerville, provided that it is scaled appropriately (Baskerville seems to be a slightly shorter font than TNR). Indeed, a guide (which can be found [here](http://www.pctex.com/files/managed/f/f5/guide2.pdf)) says the mtpro2 "fonts also turn out to be quite compatible with various other text fonts, though the text font size may have to be adjusted slightly, so that the x-heights will match."

Here's a small example to demonstrate the issue.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{mtpro2}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Baskerville}

\begin{document}
\noindent For any integer $n$ and prime number $p$, we want to solve $x^2 - ny^2 = p$.
\end{document}
```

The output produced is [image: output]

It's clear that the math text is significantly taller than the text surrounding it. 
How can I properly scale the math characters so that they integrate seamlessly with the Monotype Baskerville family?

EDIT: I should mention that one solution I know is to use something to the effect of

```
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1.05]{Baskerville}
```

which seems to do the trick, but I prefer to keep the Baskerville in 11pt, if possible.

Comment: Some traditional TeX fonts are set up in a way which permits you to easily specify a scaling factor when loading the package. Does `mtpro2` offer this? If not, then I think you would have to create modified font definition files in order to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this worked for me.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{mtpro2}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1.1]{Baskerville}

\begin{document}
\noindent For any integer $n$ and prime number $p$, we want to solve $x^2 - ny^2 = p$.
\end{document}
```

Bringing down the font size to 10pt, but then scaling it up by 110%, leaves you with an 11pt font. You then need to adjust the margins and the linespread by a similar factor to keep everything looking nice, but otherwise this solution is quite effective.

Still, I'm open to it if anyone knows a way of solving this problem by simply shrinking the mtpro2 font, which would probably be less roundabout.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is taken from [my own answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439463/164314), where I want to scale *up* MathTime Pro 2.

The task here is to match the x-heights of Baskerville and MathTime Pro 2. On the one hand, the x-height of Baskerville is `415/1000`. On the other hand, MathTime Pro 2 has three different x-heights: `457/1000`, `491/1000` and `524/1000` for `\displaystyle`/`\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`, respectively (because it uses optical sizes).

Since you wish *not to change Baskerville*, we must scale *down* MathTime Pro 2. Using my implementation, we just provide three different factors: `415/457`, `415/491` and `415/524`, and we’re done!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}% Option no-math is important!
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Baskerville}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% My implementation: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439463/164314
\makeatletter
% Customize different scaling factors here
\newcommand*{\mtpscale@scaled}{0.9080963}% 415/457
\newcommand*{\mtpscale@scriptscaled}{0.8452138}% 415/491
\newcommand*{\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled}{0.7919847}% 415/524
% Fonts available in the `lite' version
% Source code found in `mtpro2.sty'
\DeclareFontShape{LMP1}{mtt}{m}{it}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2mif
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2mis
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2mit}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP2}{mtt}{m}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2syf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2sys
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2syt}{\skewchar\font32}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP3}{mtt}{m}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2exa
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2exa
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2exa}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mtt}{b}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2mbf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2mbs
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2mbt}{}% (MJ)
% Fonts available in the `complete' version
\ifmtp@full
% Source code found in `mtpro2.sty'
\DeclareFontShape{LMP1}{mtt}{b}{it}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2bmif
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2bmis
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2bmit}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP2}{mtt}{b}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2bsyf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2bsys
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2bsyt}{\skewchar\font32}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP2}{mtt}{eb}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2hsyf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2hsys
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2hsyt}{\skewchar\font32}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP3}{mtt}{b}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2bexa
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2bexa
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2bexa}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP3}{mtt}{eb}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2hexa
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2hexa
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2hexa}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2sya}{m}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2syaf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2syas
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2syat}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2sya}{b}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2bsyaf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2bsyas
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2bsyat}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2sya}{eb}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2hsyaf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2hsyas
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2hsyat}{}%
% Source code found in `umt2ms.fd'
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mt2ms}{\skewchar\font42}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2ms}{m}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2mcf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2mcs
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2mct}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2ms}{m}{it}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2msf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2mss
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2mst}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2ms}{b}{it}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2bmsf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2bmss
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2bmst}{}%
% Source code found in `umt2mf.fd'
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mt2mf}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2mf}{m}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2mff
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2mfs
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2mft}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2mf}{b}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2bmff
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2bmfs
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2bmft}{}%
% Source code found in `umt2bb.fd'
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mt2bb}{\skewchar\font45}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2bb}{m}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2bbf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2bbs
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2bbt}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2bb}{m}{it}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2bbif
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2bbis
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2bbit}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2bb}{b}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2bbdf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2bbds
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2bbdt}{}%
% Source code found in `umt2hrb.fd'
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mt2hrb}{\skewchar\font45}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2hrb}{m}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2hrbf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2hrbs
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2hrbt}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2hrb}{m}{it}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2hbif
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2hbis
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2hbit}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2hrb}{b}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2hrbdf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2hrbds
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2hrbdt}{}%
\fi
\makeatother

\newcommand{\test}{%
  \text{For any integer }n
  \text{ and prime number }p
  \text{, we want to solve }x^2 - ny^2 = p\text{.}}

\begin{document}
\noindent For any integer $n$ and prime number $p$, we want to solve $x^2 - ny^2 = p$.

\noindent ${\textstyle\test}$

\noindent ${\scriptstyle\test}$

\noindent ${\scriptscriptstyle\test}$
\[
\begin{aligned}
x_{\text{apple},n_{\text{apple},n}} & \ge x_{\text{banana},n_{\text{banana},n}} \quad \text{for } n = 1,\dotsc,10, \\
x_{\text{apple},n_{\text{apple},n}} & < x_{\text{banana},n_{\text{banana},n}} \quad \text{for } n = 11,\dotsc,20.
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: New implementation]