# mtpro2 SQRT with root index affect the subsequent spacing

Tags: spacing, mtpro

I recently installed math professional II font (mtpro2 lite). It works fine except that the SQRT with root index sucks.

```
\[ \sqrt[100]{1000000} = 1000 \quad \sqrt[3]{1000000} = 100 \]

\[ \SQRT[100]{1000000} = 1000 \quad \SQRT[3]{1000000}= 100 \]
```

Output

[image: mtpro2sqrt]

Is this a problem of the lite version (intended or not)? Does the complete version have this problem too? How can I define a new command to handle the situation automatically?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I can confirm that the full `mtpro2` package suffers the same problem. My system runs MacOSX 10.10.4, and I use the version of pdfLaTeX that comes with MacTeX2015.

Comment: Yup, same here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know exactly why this fixes the problem, but it seems to. ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{mtpro2}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\SQRTFIX}[2][ ]{{\hphantom{\scriptscriptstyle{#1}}}\SQRT[\mathllap{#1}]{#2}}


\begin{document}

\[ \sqrt[100]{1000000} = 1000 \quad \sqrt[3]{1000000} = 100 \]

\[
 \SQRT[100]{1000000}  = 1000  \quad \SQRT[3]{1000000} = 100 
\]

\[
 \SQRTFIX[100]{1000000} =1000 \quad \SQRTFIX[3]{1000000} = 100 
 \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The second image simply shows in the yellow box what the original $\SQRT$ does and in the blue box what $\SQRTFIX$ does.

[image]

Comment: Good eyesight! Thanks to you, I was able to track down the bug in the `mtpro2` package.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @JPi’s amazing eyesight, I was able to track down exactly the bug in the `mtpro2` package. All credits goes to him/her.

[@JPi’s solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257823/164314) suggests that *the offsetting space is somehow the width of the root index*. I confirm this is the case. The root index is placed inside a box called `\rootbox`. Here is how LaTeX defines its placement:

```
% From ltmath.dtx:
\def\r@@t#1#2{%
  \setbox\z@\hbox{$\m@th#1\sqrtsign{#2}$}%
  \dimen@\ht\z@ \advance\dimen@-\dp\z@
  \mkern5mu\raise.6\dimen@\copy\rootbox
  \mkern-10mu\box\z@}
```

which is the default, while `mtpro2` does some similar things like:

```
% From mtpro2.dtx or mtpro2.sty
\def\R@@T#1#2{\setbox\z@\hbox{$\UPROOT@\z@\LEFTROOT@\z@\m@th#1\SQR@@T{#2}$}%
\dimen@\ht\z@\advance\dimen@-\dp\z@
\dimen@ii\dimen@
\setbox\tw@\hbox{$\m@th#1\mskip\UPROOT@ mu$}\advance\dimen@ii by1.667\wd\tw@
\setbox\tw@\hbox{$\m@th#1\mskip10mu$}%
\ifcase\SQcount@\advance\dimen@3\wd\tw@\or\advance\dimen@1.5\wd\tw@\or
\advance\dimen@\wd\tw@\fi
\mkern1mu\kern.13\dimen@\mkern-\LEFTROOT@ mu
\raise.5\dimen@ii\copy\rootbox % was .44
\mkern-1mu\kern-.13\dimen@\mkern\LEFTROOT@ mu\box\z@\kern-\wd\rootbox
\LEFTROOT\z@\UPROOT\z@}
```

Focusing on the overall structures, we see immediately that `\R@@T` has *additional* code of `\kern-\wd\rootbox`, which IMHO is utterly wrong. So here is my fix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{mtpro2}% lite or complete, does not matter here

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\R@@T
  {\kern-\wd\rootbox} % search this within \R@@T
  {} % replace it with nothing
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ \sqrt[100]{1000000} = 1000 \quad \sqrt[3]{1000000} = 100 \]
\[ \SQRT[100]{1000000} = 1000 \quad \SQRT[3]{1000000} = 100 \]
\end{document}
```

[image: sqrt]

**Note**: `\sqrt` and `\SQRT`, by design, will produce slightly different results (as seen in the above picture). `\SQRT` is supposed to be used for *really large* formulae (hence the awkward root index placement). **Please refrain from using `\SQRT` for small formulae.**

Comment: Wow!  Thanks for doing this!

Comment: @JPi You are welcome! I have been investigating my complete font set for almost two months now. It all started with [me trying to scale MathTime](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438966) (see also [Scaling the mtpro2 fonts to work with Baskerville](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/228330)). So far, I have found 13+ errors in the LaTeX support package…

Comment: I made a list of the 13+ bugs in a developing file [`mtpro2-patch.tex`](https://github.com/RuixiZhang42/font-pairing-guide/blob/master/mtpro2-patch.tex) (Warning: Repository is mostly Chinese, but this file is in English). It is, for the most part, for my personal use. So the instructions inside were telling you to modify `mtpro2.sty` directly for yourself. However, the fixes for `\undercbrace` and `\overcbrace` (among other things) were deemed too complicated so I provided new definitions.