# How to properly scale up fonts from newtxtext and mtpro2?

Tags: fonts, mtpro, newtx, scale, ctex

## Motivation

For my CJK documents, I’m mixing TeX Gyre Termes (a Times clone) with [Source Han Serif](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-serif) and TeX Gyre Heros (a Helvetica clone) with [Source Han Sans](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-sans). I’m also using the [MathTime Professional 2](https://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) fonts for my formulae. However, the Latin and math letters appear smaller than the CJK characters, so I need to scale up the former.

1. **The Roman family**: The largest cap height among the four TeX Gyre Termes fonts is `676/1000` (TeX Gyre Termes bold), while the cap height of Source Han Serif is `729/1000`. So a scale factor of `1.078402` (729/676) is fine.
2. **The sans family**: The cap height of TeX Gyre Heros is `729/1000`, while that of Source Han Sans is `733/1000`. So a scale factor of `1.005487` (733/729) is fine.
3. **The math family**: A scale factor of `1.078402` (same as the Roman family) is fine.

## My attempt

The first two requests can be met by a single line of code:

```
\usepackage[scaled=1.078402,helvratio=0.932386]{newtxtext}
```

where TeX Gyre Heros is loaded at scale `1.078402*0.932386`.

The [`mtpro2`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mtp2lite/texmf/tex/latex/mtpro2) package doesn’t come with a `scaled` key value option. To meet the third request, I resorted to a manual solution: `\DeclareMathSizes`. And, according to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75141/164314), the `amsmath` package should be loaded to use text font changing commands in mathematics that resize appropriately. But using `\DeclareMathSizes` leads to unexpected results:

#### Strange scaling within scripts

By scaling `mtpro2` *manually* via `\DeclareMathSizes`, scaling `newtxtext` *automatically* via `scaled=` and loading `amsmath`, I noticed strange scaling behaviors within math scripts. If you wish to reproduce the following result, please make sure that [NotoSerifCJKsc-[weight].otf](https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/cjk/) is installed and please compile by `XeLaTeX`:

```
% Please install Noto Serif CJK SC and compile by XeLaTeX
\documentclass[zihao=5,fontset=none,no-math,linespread=1.25]{ctexart}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
% Scale up math sizes manually
% Based on \DeclareMathSizes{10.5bp}{10.5bp}{7pt}{5pt} from the CTeX classes
\DeclareMathSizes{10.5bp}{11.365687pt}{7.548817pt}{5.392012pt}
% Scale up Latin size automatically
\usepackage[scaled=1.078402,helvratio=0.932386]{newtxtext}
% Set up CJK font
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK SC}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\measurement}[1]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
  #1 has width \the\wd0\relax}

\newcommand{\drawembox}[1]{%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{.1pt}%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \fbox{\rule[\dimexpr\the\fontdimen22#1-.5\fontdimen6#1\relax]{0pt}{\the\fontdimen6#1\relax}%
        \rule{\the\fontdimen6#1\relax}{0pt}}}
\newcommand{\drawcapline}[1]{%
  \leavevmode\rlap{\color{red}%
    \rule[\dimexpr#1-.05pt\relax]{\linewidth}{.1pt}}}

\newcommand*{\ideographicbaseline}{-.12}
\newcommand{\drawcembox}[1]{%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{.1pt}%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \fbox{\rule[\ideographicbaseline#1]{0pt}{#1}%
        \rule{#1}{0pt}}}

\begin{document}

$\null$%
\verb|\the\ccwd|: \the\ccwd\relax

\verb|\fontdimen6\font|: \the\fontdimen6\font\relax

\verb|\fontdimen6\textfont2|: \the\fontdimen6\textfont2\relax

\verb|\fontdimen6\scriptfont2|: \the\fontdimen6\scriptfont2

\verb|\fontdimen6\scriptscriptfont2|: \the\fontdimen6\scriptscriptfont2

\medskip

\hrule

\medskip

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.333\linewidth}
\verb|$M$|:

\leavevmode\rlap{\drawembox{\textfont2}}%
\drawcapline{.675\fontdimen6\textfont2}%
\measurement{$M$}

\leavevmode\rlap{\drawembox{\textfont2}}%
\drawcapline{.675\fontdimen6\textfont2}%
\measurement{$\displaystyle M$}

\leavevmode\rlap{\drawembox{\textfont2}}%
\drawcapline{.675\fontdimen6\textfont2}%
\measurement{$\textstyle M$}

\leavevmode\rlap{\drawembox{\scriptfont2}}%
\drawcapline{.722\fontdimen6\scriptfont2}%
\measurement{$\scriptstyle M$}

\leavevmode\rlap{\drawembox{\scriptscriptfont2}}%
\drawcapline{.732\fontdimen6\scriptscriptfont2}%
\measurement{$\scriptscriptstyle M$}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.333\linewidth}
\verb|\textbf{M}|:

\leavevmode\rlap{\drawembox{\textfont2}}%
\drawcapline{.676em}%
\measurement{\textbf{M}}

\leavevmode\rlap{\drawembox{\textfont2}}%
\drawcapline{.676\fontdimen6\textfont2}%
\measurement{$\displaystyle\textbf{M}$}

\leavevmode\rlap{\drawembox{\textfont2}}%
\drawcapline{.676\fontdimen6\textfont2}%
\measurement{$\textstyle\textbf{M}$}

\leavevmode\rlap{\drawembox{\scriptfont2}}%
\drawcapline{.729\fontdimen6\scriptfont2}%
\measurement{$\scriptstyle\textbf{M}$}

\leavevmode\rlap{\drawembox{\scriptscriptfont2}}%
\drawcapline{.729\fontdimen6\scriptscriptfont2}%
\measurement{$\scriptscriptstyle\textbf{M}$}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.333\linewidth}
字:

\leavevmode\rlap{\drawcembox{\ccwd}}%
\measurement{字}

\leavevmode\rlap{\drawcembox{\ccwd}}%
\measurement{$\displaystyle\text{字}$}

\leavevmode\rlap{\drawcembox{\ccwd}}%
\measurement{$\textstyle\text{字}$}

\leavevmode\rlap{\drawcembox{\fontdimen6\scriptfont2\relax}}%
\measurement{$\scriptstyle\text{字}$}

\leavevmode\rlap{\drawcembox{\fontdimen6\scriptscriptfont2\relax}}%
\measurement{$\scriptscriptstyle\text{字}$}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: Inconsistent scaling within scripts]

#### My observations

1. `\ccwd` yields the size of the em-box for CJK characters: `10.5bp = 10.539375pt`.
2. **The first 3 rows**: For `\displaystyle` or `\textstyle`, both the Latin em-box and the math em-box are properly scaled by `1.078402`, as expected.

   - **MathTime Pro 2**: The designed cap height is `675/1000`. After the manual scaling, the scaled cap height to the math em and to the `\ccwd` ratios are `0.675` and `0.72792` (0.675*729/676), respectively, as expected.
   - **TeX Gyre Termes bold**: The designed cap height is `676/1000`. After the automatic scaling, the scaled cap height to the Latin em and to the `\ccwd` ratios are `0.676` and `0.729`, respectively, as expected.
3. The 6 cap lines in the first 3 rows hardly have any distinction, as expected, although those of MathTime Pro 2 are in fact slightly lower.
4. **The 4th row**: For `\scriptstyle`, it appears that *all em-boxes are of the same size, as declared*, which means: Math em = Latin em = `\ccwd`.

   - **MathTime Pro 2**: The designed cap height is `722/1000` and its ratio to the `\ccwd` (= math em) is precisely `0.722`.
   - **TeX Gyre Termes bold**: The designed cap height is `676/1000`, but the actual cap height to the Latin em (= `\ccwd`) ratio *somehow becomes* `0.729`! It seems like the glyph is magnified by `1.078402` but somehow the em-box stays at the same size. Why?
   - The math cap line is slightly lower than the Latin one: 0.722<0.729.
5. **The 5th row**: For `\scriptscriptstyle`, it also appears that *all em-boxes are of the same size, as declared*.

   - **MathTime Pro 2**: The designed cap height is `732/1000` and its ratio to the `\ccwd` (= math em) is precisely `0.732`.
   - **TeX Gyre Termes bold**: Again, the actual cap height to the Latin em (= `\ccwd`) ratio *somehow becomes* `0.729`! Why?
   - The math cap line is slightly higher than the Latin one (by pixels if the PDF is magnified by 6400%): 0.732>0.729.

#### Summary

There are 15 glyphs drawn in the MWE, *all but 2* of which are understandably scaled. The bottom 2 glyphs in the middle column seem to be scaled while somehow maintain their em-boxes unchanged.

By pure coincidence (even with the aforementioned “mistake”), the actual cap height to `\ccwd` ratios ended up surprisingly close to each other throughout 3 fonts and 3 math styles, which were aimed at `0.729` in the beginning.

```
                     Table: Actual cap height to \ccwd ratio
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    display/text style      script style     script script style
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 mtpro2             0.72792              0.722                0.732
 Termes bold        0.729                0.729*, why?         0.729*, why?
 Source Han Serif   0.729 (by design)    0.729 (by design)    0.729 (by design)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* These should be 0.676, shouldn’t they?
```

**Added on July 4, 2018**: Here is a full table showing the strange scaling behaviors within math scripts.

[image: Scaling results]

## How to properly scale up fonts from `newtxtext` and `mtpro2`?

I got extremely lucky with the cap heights. Is this the proper way of matching these mentioned fonts? More specifically:

1. Is there a better way to scale up MathTime Pro 2? It’d be nice to use it just like `\usepackage[scaled=1.1]{newtxmath}`.

   - I’m open to modifying the `mtpro2.sty` file, as it contains *many* known problems. For instance, problems pointed out in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315010/164314) by @egreg and in [this comment](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35906306#35906306) by @DavidCarlisle.
   - In fact, a [redefinition of `\left` and `\right`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2610/164314) would break the `\LEFTRIGHT` command from accessing large curly parentheses and braces. I solved this by replacing

     ```
       \def\PEX@#1{\setbox\Pbox@\vbox{$$\left.\vcenter{\copy\prePbox@}\right)$$}%
     ```

     with

     ```
       \def\PEX@#1{\setbox\Pbox@\vbox{$$\originalleft.\vcenter{\copy\prePbox@}\originalright)$$}%
     ```
2. Why is the text font at different math styles scaled inconsistently?

Comment: Does `\mathit` work?

Comment: @cfr Yes, it does! But I hesitate to use a new math alphabet. I found loading `amsmath` seems to solve the problem (partially), but it creates something subtler. I also believe using `\mathit` makes the glyphs in the whole middle column to be scaled “twice”.

Comment: Why? It exists whether you use it or not.

Comment: @cfr You’re right. But my question leans more on understanding how scaling works and applying it properly. The non-scaled `\textit` problem disappeared after I read [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75141/164314). I removed that MWE to highlight the very subtle and previously hidden scaling problem in math scripts.

Comment: Why do you have stuff crossed out in your question? If we don't need to read it, delete it; if we do, don't cross it out.

Comment: @cfr My question had introductions that went through many edits. The strike-through texts are intended for people who saw the early introductions to notice the differences. The main question remains, except that I find the word “inconsistently” more appropriate than “incorrectly” due to my new findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I’ve finally found satisfactory answers.

- **Q1**: Is there a better way to scale up MathTime Pro 2?

  - **A**: Yes!!! And there’s no need to modify `mtpro2.sty`!
- **Q2**: Why is the text font at different math styles scaled inconsistently?

  - **A**: It isn’t. The text font is scaled *consistently*.

    When inside `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`, the claim

    > all em-boxes are of the same size, as declared

    is *not true*. In fact, the Latin em-box is scaled by `1.078402` as specified by `newtxtext`. I mistakenly drew math em-boxes for both Latin text and CJK text, which led to a *wrong* observation.

**Side note**: If `\usepackage[scaled=1.078402]{mtpro2}` were possible, it’d make the ratios between math cap height and CJK em equaling `0.72792`, `0.77861` and `0.78939` (which are `1.078402 * <designed values>`) at the 3 math styles, respectively. Then, the last two scales may not blend well with Source Han Serif.

## My implementation

The font declaration source code can be found [here](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mtp2lite/texmf/tex/latex/mtpro2) on CTAN. We can simply override how the MathTime Pro 2 fonts are loaded.

There’re [68 fonts of MathTime Pro 2](https://www.pctex.com/68MTPro2Fonts.html) (complete version). The 5 fonts `mt2xl`, `mt2exe`, `mt2xxxl`, `mt2exf` and `mt2exg` contain extra large parentheses, braces, radicals, integrals, etc. These 5 fonts have *absolute* design sizes, so they do *not* need to be scaled.

To allow different scaling factors being applied to different optical sizes, I created 3 macros: `\mtpscale@scaled`, `\mtpscale@scriptscaled` and `\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled`. These 3 macros are to be applied to the other 63 fonts. Although large symbols `mt2exa`, `mt2bexa` and `mt2hexa` don’t have optical sizes, they should be scaled using these 3 different factors as well.

Therefore, the total number of `\DeclareFontShape`’s we need to override is precisely `(63+3*2)/3 = 23`. Among these 23 `\DeclareFontShape`’s, 12 of them are written in the `.sty` file, while the other 11 are written in the four `.fd` files. So we also need the four `\DeclareFontFamily`’s from the `.fd` files, too.

```
% Please install Noto Serif CJK SC and compile by XeLaTeX
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK SC}
\usepackage[scaled=1.0976331,helvratio=0.9160502]{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% My implementation
\makeatletter
% Customize different scaling factors here
\newcommand*{\mtpscale@scaled}{1.0814815}
\newcommand*{\mtpscale@scriptscaled}{1.0124654}
\newcommand*{\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled}{1}
% Fonts available in the `lite' version
% Source code found in `mtpro2.sty'
\DeclareFontShape{LMP1}{mtt}{m}{it}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2mif
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2mis
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2mit}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP2}{mtt}{m}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2syf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2sys
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2syt}{\skewchar\font32}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP3}{mtt}{m}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2exa
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2exa
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2exa}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mtt}{b}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2mbf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2mbs
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2mbt}{}% (MJ)
% Fonts available in the `complete' version
\ifmtp@full
% Source code found in `mtpro2.sty'
\DeclareFontShape{LMP1}{mtt}{b}{it}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2bmif
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2bmis
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2bmit}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP2}{mtt}{b}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2bsyf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2bsys
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2bsyt}{\skewchar\font32}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP2}{mtt}{eb}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2hsyf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2hsys
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2hsyt}{\skewchar\font32}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP3}{mtt}{b}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2bexa
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2bexa
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2bexa}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP3}{mtt}{eb}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2hexa
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2hexa
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2hexa}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2sya}{m}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2syaf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2syas
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2syat}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2sya}{b}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2bsyaf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2bsyas
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2bsyat}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2sya}{eb}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2hsyaf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2hsyas
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2hsyat}{}%
% Source code found in `umt2ms.fd'
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mt2ms}{\skewchar\font42}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2ms}{m}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2mcf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2mcs
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2mct}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2ms}{m}{it}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2msf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2mss
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2mst}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2ms}{b}{it}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2bmsf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2bmss
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2bmst}{}%
% Source code found in `umt2mf.fd'
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mt2mf}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2mf}{m}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2mff
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2mfs
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2mft}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2mf}{b}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2bmff
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2bmfs
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2bmft}{}%
% Source code found in `umt2bb.fd'
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mt2bb}{\skewchar\font45}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2bb}{m}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2bbf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2bbs
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2bbt}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2bb}{m}{it}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2bbif
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2bbis
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2bbit}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2bb}{b}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2bbdf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2bbds
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2bbdt}{}%
% Source code found in `umt2hrb.fd'
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mt2hrb}{\skewchar\font45}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2hrb}{m}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2hrbf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2hrbs
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2hrbt}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2hrb}{m}{it}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2hbif
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2hbis
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2hbit}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2hrb}{b}{n}{%
  <-7> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscriptscaled] mt2hrbdf
  <7-9> s*[\mtpscale@scriptscaled] mt2hrbds
  <9-> s*[\mtpscale@scaled] mt2hrbdt}{}%
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$M\text{M字}_{M\text{M字}_{M\text{M字}}}$.
\end{document}
```

Voilà!

[image: After scaling]

And here’s what the output looks like without scaling:

[image: Before scaling]

My solution can also be applied to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/228330/164314).

Answer (score 1):

Here’s an approach that allows you to use modern OpenType fonts, and scales as many of them automatically for you as possible.

It still uses the `ctexat` documentclass, but sets up the fonts with `mathspec` so that you can still use OTF text fonts with the math font you chose.  Since you were using `newtxtext`, I use the OpenType version of Termes from the newtx collection, but you could substitute any other font if that’s not a requirement. I also replace the letters and digits with the text font so that numbers in text mode and math mode match. (If you would rather use an OTF math font instead, you can load `unicode-math` and the math font will scale for you automatically as well.)

For the purposes of loading a legacy math font, this document computes the ratio of the x-heights of both the text font and the math font, as well as the font sizes of the main math font, script font and script-script font.  You will want to use whatever option your package supports to scale it until the ratio of x-heights is 1.0.  (I didn’t bother to remove the spurious pt afterward.)

Since I don’t have the commercial fonts you selected, I substituted `newtxmath` for this example.

```
% Please install all the fonts needed, and compile by XeLaTeX
\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec} % Workaround for option clash
\documentclass[zihao=5,fontset=none,no-math,linespread=1.25]{ctexart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % I do not have these fonts to test.
\usepackage[scaled=1.05159]{newtxmath} % For testing purposes.
\usepackage{mathspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}
\setmainfont{TeXGyreTermesX} % Matches newtxtext.
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK SC}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setCJKsansfont{Noto Sans CJK SC}
\setmonofont{Inconsolata}
\setCJKmonofont{Source Han Sans SC}

\newlength{\textxheight}
\newlength{\mathxheight}
\newlength{\xratio}

\settoheight{\textxheight}{x}
\settoheight{\mathxheight}{\(x\)}
\setlength{\xratio}{\dimexpr 1.0pt*(\numexpr\textxheight\relax)/(\numexpr\mathxheight\relax)\relax}

% Now that we’ve computed the ratio of x-heights, change the letters of the
% math font to match the text.  If you don’t want to, at least consider
% changing the digits.
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){TeXGyreTermesX}

\begin{document}
The ratio of the heights of x and \(x\) is {\the\xratio}.

I did not remove the spurious ``pt."  Thank e-tex.

Scale your math font until the above says 1.0pt.

\( \text{\the\fontdimen6\textfont2}_{\text{\the\fontdimen6\scriptfont2}_\text{\the\fontdimen6\scriptscriptfont2}} \)

\( \emptyset M\text{M字}_{\emptyset M\text{M字}_{\emptyset M\text{M字}}} \).
\end{document}
```

[image: Scale test]

Also note that `polyglossia` would allow you to change between different East Asian scripts, should a single `\setCJKmainfont` not suffice.

Comment: Wow! This is very neat! Thank you for detailed answers! I should’ve read the `fontspec` and `mathspec` manuals more thoroughly. However (and this is *very* subjective), I’m more comfortable with manual scaling as opposed to automatic matching x- or cap-heights (I’m paranoid about “black box” code). **Side notes**: 1) The lite version of MTPro2 is actually free; 2) When setting mono fonts with Source Han Sans SC, I wouldn’t recommend scaling Inconsolata: Mono CJK should blend with “half-width” Latin. So, non-scaled Inconsolata, or Source Han Sans HW SC (alias Noto Sans Mono CJK SC) suffices.

Comment: @RuixiZhang In that case, `fontspec` lets you provide a manual scaling factor, like `\setsansfont[Scale=1.1]{TeX Gyre Heros}`. My method of comparing the scale of two fonts is a bit of a hack, but you can check out the source code of, e.g. `tgpagella.sty` to see another method.