# x-height of newtxtext font

Tags: fonts

I am trying to scale the `mtpro2` font to work with the `newtxtext` font package. That is because I observed that the inline math equations in the footnotes are slightly bigger or rather different than the text around it. I am sure that it *is* the case.

I have been trying to follow the answer of the question [Scaling the mtpro2 fonts to work with Baskerville](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228330/scaling-the-mtpro2-fonts-to-work-with-baskerville), and I only have one problem: what is the x-height of `newtxtext`? If I use the code from that answer without changing it, then the resulting math font will be smaller than the text font.

Here is an MWE for you to test your answer:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
    Some ordinarily sized text. $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$\footnote{Some ordinarily sized footnote text. $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ Here are two numbers, the first one is text, the second one is math: 0$0$}
\end{document}
```

P.S. Do you know an archive that has the x-heights of all the fonts? It will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mtpro2` fonts are optically scaled and you need to apply different magnifications in order that they match the size of NewTX.

However this would make the digits smaller, so I also redefine the math codes of the digits to use the text font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}

\DeclareFontShape{LMP1}{mtt}{m}{it}{
  <-7>  s*[0.8588]  mt2mif
  <7-9> s*[0.9165]  mt2mis
  <9->  s*[0.97375] mt2mit
}{}
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"30}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"32}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"33}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"34}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"36}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"37}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"38}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"39}


\textheight=4cm

\begin{document}

\sbox0{x}\the\ht0\ \sbox0{$x$}\the\ht0

{\footnotesize\sbox0{x}\the\ht0\ \sbox0{$x$}\the\ht0}

{\tiny\sbox0{x}\the\ht0\ \sbox0{$x$}\the\ht0}

Some ordinarily sized text. $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$\footnote{Some ordinarily 
  sized footnote text. $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ Here are two numbers, the first
  one is text, the second one is math: 0$0$}

\end{document}
```

You may need to do similar adjustments also for other `mtpro2` fonts.

How did I get the factors? Comment out the `\DeclareFontShape` declaration and you'll see the different heights, from which I computed the scaling factors.

[image]

Here are the figures without the scaling.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works well for me.